# How to get Location in Response Header use HttpResponseMessage in windows phone

Tags: httprequest, httpclient, httpresponse, request-headers, response-headers

I want get Location in Response Header but i can't see this in Response. How to get this. Please help me.

```
 var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = false });
    FormUrlEncodedContent postData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("background","1"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("line1","Content1"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("line2","Content2")
                        });
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("URL", postData);
                    string rp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```